# Splitting html table in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, split, html-table

I have a html file which has a huge table with 4 columns and multiple rows. I want to display it in an asp 2.0/3.5 page, such that it's first 2 columns appear in one area and other two appear in another area adjacent to it. Some thing like splitting the table in two and displaying. Is there any way i can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i wrote a RegEx and split the file in two html files. then i loaded each of them inside a div tag. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate the table? That will determine how you split it.

Also, I don't understand the benefit of just putting the two halves side by side. Did you intend to be able to hide one half?

Comment: i'm trying to implement online file comparison, so i've got output in html form from beyond compare. It generates a html report with one huge table. I want it to split in two separate tables so that i can control each result.

Comment: Ok, this really becomes a BC question, but look to see if they can produce the output in XML (and process yourself), or if their HTML report is XHTML (in which case, it's XML and you can process it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I would split the dataset into two seperate datasets with the appropriate columns.  I would also have two seperate GridViews to display the different datasets.

To minimize code duplication, I would use ASP.NET themes to skin the datasets and I would also hook into the same GridView functions (Update Command, DataBound, etc) so that you don't have to re-write much.

If you're doing the tables by hand, it's just a question of changing where you're response.writing the  and 's to.